# State of the art language translation toolkit

Tags: nlp, nltk, machine-translation, moses

I need to translate Spanish tweets into english for my research. I find some toolkit. Among them, [Moses](http://www.statmt.org/moses/) is used by some research papers and other emerging toolkits used them as a baseline for evaluation purpose. So i am considering it as a candidate. Also, I found a toolkit from Stanford university called [Phrsal](http://nlp.stanford.edu/phrasal/), which also seems to be good. The last one I found is from renowned `nltk` library. It also has a [translate](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.translate.html) package. Every one of them states that they used `phrase based statistical machine translation` technique along with some other techinques. Now my question is, from a practical or theoretical point of view, which will be best to use for tweets translation. Or `google translator api` would be the best solution?

Comment: You might as well take a look at [Google Neural Machine Translation](https://research.googleblog.com/2016/09/a-neural-network-for-machine.html). We're investigating whether we can use this for our company documentation. It isn't statistical anymore, but based on neural networks. You can [try it yourselves](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow).